# Return array value from produce function | immer.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, immer.js

I am using immer.js to perform operations on arrays in the state.

Arrays: basicRecipe and recipeBasicRecipe.

I am modifying the draft.basicRecipe in the produce function. My objective is to return the updated "draft.basicRecipe" value and store the same in temparray1.

```
    let temparray1 = produce(state, draft => {
      
      draft.basicRecipe = draft.basicRecipe.map(item => {
        let element = draft.recipeBasicRecipes.find(e => e._id === item._id);
        console.log(element);
        if (element) {
          item.details = item.details.map(e => {
            let detail = element.details.find(d => d._id === e._id);
            if (detail) {
              e.rate = detail.rate;
            }
            return e;
          });
        }
        return item;
      });
      return draft.basicRecipe;
    });

    console.log(temparray1);
```

When I return the draft I am able to see updated basicRecipe nested in output.
I am getting the below error when I try to return the array i.e draft.basicRecipe

```
 [Immer] An immer producer returned a new value *and* modified its draft. Either return a new value *or* modify the draft
```

Answer (score -1):

This code is a mess.  You are using `map` which returns a new array but you're also trying to mutate the original draft object.

This is still unreadable and confusing, but at least by using `forEach` instead of `map` we are just mutating and not trying to do two things at once.

```
let temparray1 = produce(state, (draft) => {
  draft.basicRecipe.forEach((item) => {
    let element = draft.recipeBasicRecipes.find((e) => e._id === item._id);
    if (element) {
      item.details.forEach((e) => {
        let detail = element.details.find((d) => d._id === e._id);
        if (detail) {
          e.rate = detail.rate;
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```